# PL/SQL How to INSERT with a subquery and an argument

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure that requires a string as input

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testing(MYVAR VARCHAR) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ( (SELECT id FROM articles), MYVAR );  --WRONG
```

The insert query is wrong, basically the table mytable has only 2 fields:

```
idarticles | variable
```

With the subquery I wanna select all the `article ID` and insert them as a pair with the MYVAR arg.

How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: That would leave you with duplicate values for ID: why would you want to do that?  If ID is the table's primary key it doesn't make sense, and anyway the primary key constraint would hurl.  And if ID isn't the table's primary key why is it called ID?

Comment: @apc: acutally the subquery has a WHERE clause generated by some others argument that makes this procedure with a sense :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
  INSERT INTO mytable (idarticles,variable)
    SELECT id, myvar FROM articles
```

It's the same as including any other variable or constant, or literal in your `SELECT` statement:

```
 SELECT 100, 'Foo', ID FROM Customer
```

Comment: @a_horse: phew! It feels good to be out of the rain! :D It finally happened, being the fastest gun this time :D

Comment: But guys did you get the  myvar isn't a field but is a string passed as argument? with that query oracle will not try to fetch a "myvar" field in articles table? (there isn't any myvar field there)

Comment: @yes, yes, you can include any variable or constant in your SELECT statement.

Comment: How oracle can understand if myvar is acutually a field of the table or a variable?

Comment: @yes123 - Oracle will figure out where the name is defined; see this on [name resolution](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fundamentals.htm#CHDDABDD). It's helpful to have a naming convention that stops you accidentally duplicating a column name with a variable name - e.g. prefixing parameter names with `p_`, local variables with `l_`, etc. It would only be confusing here if either table had a column called `myvar`, but it's better to get into the habit of always doing it rather than tripping over it one day.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (SELECT id, MYVAR FROM articles);
```